# change style dynamically of none html element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using angularJs and want to change the style of an attribute dynamically.
Normally I would do this with `ng-style` in the html element.

But I want to apply styles to the track of a range input.
This element can be accessed in css like that: `.slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track`(As Example for the webkit selector). Can I change the style for such an attribute in a function where I have the id for this element?

E.g (how I would do it in jquery):

```
$scope.change = function(id, value) {
        $('#'+id+'::-webkit-slider-runnable-track').css('background-image',value);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript generally don't have access to pseudo elements, one possible workaround would be to insert a style tag

```
$scope.change = function(id, value) {
    var style  = document.createElement('style');
    var styles = '{ background: red }';

    style.innerHTML = '#' + id + '::-webkit-slider-runnable-track ' + styles;
    document.head.appendChild(style)
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3q2rwyfh/)

Another way would be to keep the styles in the stylesheet, and just use a different class for a different style

```
#test.red::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background : red;
}
```

and then do

```
document.getElementById('test').classList.add('red');
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/3q2rwyfh/1/)

Comment: This will add a new style element on each change. Assuming the change function will be called a lot of times I would have many style tags in my html afterwards, am I right?

Comment: I added a style tag with bindings directly to the html (Which is kinda what you suggested with a little bit less overload).
It seems like I have to access the elements with an id and a class: `#id.class::selector`. It doesn't work with the id only.

Answer (score 0):

for AngularJs I recommend not to use $scope but use service, factory or directory instead for CSS type of work on html template.

however if you must still want to take this approach you can:

```
$scope.change = function(id, cssClass, add) {
    var el = angular.element(document.querySelector(id));

    if (add) {
       el.addClass(cssClass);
    } else {
       el.removeClass(cssClass);
    }
}
```

where you can pass `id` for element, `cssClass` from your css class and use `add` as bool value; pass what ever you want.